# Azure Static Web / Azure Functions - missing Authentication Header

Tags: azure, azure-static-web-app, azure-static-web-app-routing

We host an SPA (angular) with Auth0 on an Azure Static Webapp and use Azure Functions (nodejs) as backend. The functions are also displayed correctly under API.

[image]

If I want to call the functions from the frontend via https://mycool.azurestaticapps.net/api, the request works, but the authentication information (header) from the backend is empty and is not sent correctly. What am I doing wrong?

If I call the Azure Functions directly (https://mycool.azurewebsites.net/api), it works, the header information is completely available.

How do I have to configure the "staticwebapp.config.json" so that it works? here my current config:

```
{
  "routes": [
    {
      "route": "/api*",
      "allowedRoles": ["authenticated"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi 
Can you check if your staticwebapp.config.json, you need to configure the routes that should be treated as authenticated routes. if you need I can give u a syntax for that.

Comment: @MohamedAzarudeenZ i've tried several thing, but i doesn't work. i added my current config (see my post).